# Tensorflow: concatenating multiple tf.Dataset very slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am on Tensorflow 1.10

Right now I am not sure if this is a bug.

I have been trying to concatenate about 100 Datasets which I generated from multiple tf.data.Dataset.from_generator.

```
for i in range(1, 100):
        dataset = dataset.concatenate(
            tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gens[i], (tf.int8, tf.int32), output_shapes=(
                (256, 256), (1))))
        print(i)
 print("before iterator")
 iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
 print("after iterator")
```

running the `make_one_shot_iterator()` takes really long.

Anyone knows a fix?

EDIT:

It looks like that  `_make_dataset.add_to_graph(ops.get_default_graph())`
seems to get called over and over again resulting in a few million calls of the function. 
(https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py   function make_one_shot_iterator  line 162)

Comment: I am facing this issue as well. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're using TF 1.10?

Comment: @Colonder during the time i posted this question, it was actually on of the more recent versions of tensorflow :)

Comment: @183.amir yes i did. I edited as an answer down below

Answer (score 0):

Running `concatenate`is actually not the best thing to do for multiple tensors or generators like this.

A better way is to use `flat_map` https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#flat_map . I did updated the Example a while a go to show how you can use this for multiple tensors or files.

Comment: Could you please post a more clear answer? I have several datasets already created (coming from tfrecords) and I really want to concatenate them as in the order of samples is important for me. How can I concatenate several datasets using flat_map?

Comment: Oh in case you use tf Records you can just use the tfrecord dataset and pass in the file names as an array

Comment: I cannot do that since I apply a different map on each tfrecord and then I want to concatenate them.

Comment: You could try creating an array or tensor from your mapped tfrecords and use tf flat_map afterwards to open up the array structure. I think I have used something similar but I can’t find the old code right now.